# when page load mouseover is automatic work

Tags: jquery, css

I have this problem when page load `mouseover` is automatic works

Here is the `css` and `javascript`:

```
$('.divTop').mouseover(function(){
        $('.private').stop().animate({"top":"0px"},200);
        $('.corporate').stop().animate({"bottom":"0px"},200);
    });
    $('.private, .corporate').mouseout(function(){
        $('.private').stop().animate({top:"-50%"},200);
        $('.corporate').stop().animate({bottom:"-50%"},200);
    });
.private{
    background-image:url('/CapitalBank/img/icon/umbrella.png');
    /* border-bottom:1px solid #d2ab67; */
    background-size:50px;
    top:-50%;
}
.corporate{
    border-top:1px solid #d2ab67;
    background-image:url('/CapitalBank/img/icon/key.png');
    bottom:-50%;
}
.divTop{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    /* outline:1px solid white; */
    background-image: url('/CapitalBank/img/bg/ibank.png');
    background-position:center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: mouseover work automatically

Comment: You want disable this function or bind this function on some event, or what ?

Comment: I want when I really hover over the div start mouseover efect
(sorry my English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.divTop').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.private').stop().animate({"top":"0px"},200);
    $('.corporate').stop().animate({"bottom":"0px"},200);
});
$('.private, .corporate').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.private').stop().animate({top:"-50%"},200);
    $('.corporate').stop().animate({bottom:"-50%"},200);
});
```